# Cannot connect Azure Web App - NodeJS to Azure Mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, azure, azure-database-mysql

I am using azure connection string (from Azure portal) for Node.js app, still cannot connect to Azure Database for Mysql server.

var conn = mysql.createConnection({
    host: yourhost,
    user: "username",
    password: "password",
    database: "database",
    port: 3306,
    ssl:{ca:fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/baltimore.pem')}});

I get following error:
"Error: MySQL server is requesting the old and insecure pre-4.1 auth mechanism.Upgrade the user password or use the {insecureAuth: true} option."

But I can connect using Mysql Benchmark same credentials.

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Database for MySQL is incompatible with the [mysqljs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) connector library. See [issue 1729](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1729) for details and [pull 1730](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/pull/1730) for a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for an answer,  now it gives an error : \lib\protocol\Parser.js:80
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:344:11)

Comment: @RuslanSafarov That looks like an error with whatever HTTP library you are using; once the HTTP headers have been sent to the client, they can't be modified.

Comment: I am using standart http and Express. I was using createPool,  now when I use createConnection i get another error :  The solution is:  undefined
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:873:11)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:557:26)

Comment: Anyway thanks for an answer :) I guess I am missing something, I will accept answer.