# Bad handshake or ECONNRESET Azure Mysql Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, azure, knex.js

Similar issues have been reported, but I can't work around with there solutions.

I have an express.js app using KNEX to connect to a mysql database hosted in Azure.

I can connect to the DB perfectly from console command or mysql workbench.

However, no way to achieve the same from my node app.

My connection object is the same though:

```
config.knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
        host: 'wineserver.mysql.database.azure.com',
        user: 'BurgerAndGreenBeans@wineserver',
        password: 'FromageDeChevre',
        database: 'gdpr',
        insecureAuth: true
    },
    pool: {
         min: 0
    },
    debug: ['ComQueryPacket']
});
```

Everytime I start the app, I get alternatively either one error or another one:

**#1**

```
Unhandled rejection Error: read ECONNRESET
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1050:11)
at TCP.onread (net.js:582:26)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:141:48)
at Protocol.handshake (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:52:41)
at Connection.connect (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:130:18)
at C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\mysql\index.js:106:18
at Promise._execute (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\debuggability.js:300:9)
at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:483:18)
at new Promise (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:79:10)
at Client_MySQL.acquireRawConnection (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\mysql\index.js:104:12)
at Object.create (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\knex\lib\client.js:239:16)
at Pool._createResource (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\generic-pool\lib\generic-pool.js:354:17)
at Pool.dispense [as _dispense] (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\generic-pool\lib\generic-pool.js:314:10)
at Pool.acquire (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\generic-pool\lib\generic-pool.js:436:8)
at C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\knex\lib\client.js:289:19
at Promise._execute (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\debuggability.js:300:9)
at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:483:18)
at new Promise (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:79:10)
```

Process finished with exit code 0

or

**#2**

```
Unhandled rejection Error: ER_HANDSHAKE_ERROR: Bad handshake
at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:52:14)
at Handshake.ErrorPacket (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Handshake.js:103:18)
at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:280:23)
at Parser.write (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:75:12)
at Protocol.write (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:39:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:103:28)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:178:18)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:136:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:561:20)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:141:48)
at Protocol.handshake (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:52:41)
at Connection.connect (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:130:18)
at C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\mysql\index.js:106:18
at Promise._execute (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\debuggability.js:300:9)
at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:483:18)
at new Promise (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:79:10)
at Client_MySQL.acquireRawConnection (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\mysql\index.js:104:12)
at Object.create (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\knex\lib\client.js:239:16)
at Pool._createResource (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\generic-pool\lib\generic-pool.js:354:17)
at Pool.dispense [as _dispense] (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\generic-pool\lib\generic-pool.js:314:10)
at Pool.acquire (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\generic-pool\lib\generic-pool.js:436:8)
at C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\knex\lib\client.js:289:19
at Promise._execute (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\debuggability.js:300:9)
at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:483:18)
at new Promise (C:\Projects\gdpr\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:79:10)
Process finished with exit code 0
```

It seems to be a kind of incompatibility between Node and Azure's mysql server.

Did anyone experienced the same ?

Comment: Try to replace `user: 'BurgerAndGreenBeans@wineserver'` with `user: 'BurgerAndGreenBean'`. Your connection URI is basically `USER:PASSWORD@SERVER/DATABASE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The similar question: [Connecting to Azure Database for MySQL in npm/mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44514902/connecting-to-azure-database-for-mysql-in-npm-mysql/44534856#44534856). As @Gary Liu pointed out, you may use [pull 1730](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/pull/1730) for a workaround.

Please modify the `package.json` as:

```
"dependencies": {
    "knex": "^0.13.0",
    "mysql": "git://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#e3e123e9af7c0829a6c1417d911572a75b4a5f95"
 }
```

then, run `npm install` to install this version.