# Error: read ECONNRESET when connected to a mysql server with Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, azure, express

I'm trying to establish a simple connection to my database with the mysql npm package. At first glance, everything works fine and I can get the information I need, however, if I leave the server running for some time I get the following error:
           Error: `read ECONNRESET
                  at TCP.onStreamRead`

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();`
```

`const mysql = require('mysql');`

```
 const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'XXXX.mysql.database.azure.com',
  user: 'XXXXX',
 password: 'XXXXX',
 database: 'XXXXX'

})
    db.connect((err)=>{
    if(err){
       console.log(err.message);
    } else {
        console.log('Connected to the database');
    }
})
```

As far as I understand the problem stems from the database connection being in idle mode. Do I need to configure the Azure server or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Did you check in the azure panel if the server is running?

Comment: @nbk yes, the server is running

Comment: Try it with mysql workbench and see if it can get a connection. If not see if there is an error https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-exceptions  maybe a restart helps.

Comment: Tried it with the workbench, tried restarting the database, no luck so far..

Comment: contact the support.I am wondering why nothing shows up in the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things to try:

- You can try creating connection pool instead of `**createConnection**`

  **mysql.createPool({});**
- Modify your package.json like below:

```html
    "dependencies": {
        "mysql": "git://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#e3e123e9af7c0829a6c1417d911572a75b4a5f95"
      },
```

It is described in detail here:

[Bad handshake or ECONNRESET Azure Mysql Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45171773/bad-handshake-or-econnreset-azure-mysql-nodejs)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c8fedbcc-909d-41ce-8c72-0374f76fdf82/cannot-connect-from-nodejs?forum=AzureDatabaseforMySQL

Hope it helps.

Comment: It seems the createPool solved the problem. Thank you for your help and sorry for the late reply!

Comment: Glad to know it helped!!

Comment: @MohitVerma can you explain how this works? and why that error happens?